# Beethoven and parallel minor keys

Tags: composition, beethoven

I read somewhere recently that Beethoven considered the minor and major keys to be "one and the same"

The quote i reference was not referring to the relative minor (ie. Am in key of C), but was referring to the parallel minor (Cm in key of C).

Could anyone elucidate further on what, if anything, the original author meant by this?

Thanks

Edit:

Here is the original source, it's at 10:37: https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx5etB0VIZa5NHXxqxgp9N4ul74H7fF3Bm

Comment: “I read somewhere recently…” If you can provide a quote why not provide the source as well?

Comment: Not only Beethoven. I think a lot of musos consider the same. I did when writing stuff 50 yrs ago, not even understanding the 'theory' behind it.

Comment: I doubt this claim when Wikipedia maintains an article on [Beethoven and C minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beethoven_and_C_minor) and does not do the same for Beethoven and C major.

Comment: Could you please add more about the context, or identify or help us find the source? I could imagine someone meaning *something* by this phrase—maybe about modal mixture—but it would just be an unfounded guess without more explanation.

Comment: Remembering a quote without remembering who it is attributed to is a common occurence for me! - Here it is at 10:37 -  https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx5etB0VIZa5NHXxqxgp9N4ul74H7fF3Bm

Comment: Thanks! I'll let someone else explain better, but I heard this referred to as "modal ambiguity." I heard about it more when looking at Brahms, but I guess Beethoven was leading towards that: The idea of "I'm in C." "Major or minor?" "Does it matter? Kinda both. Just call it C." It's kind of like taking the idea of [modal mixture](https://viva.pressbooks.pub/openmusictheory/chapter/modal-mixture/) and following it so far that it's hard to say which is the "real" mode anymore.

Comment: If you analyze enough Beethoven, you will start to see frequent modal mixture, but I’m not sure if that’s the same as treating parallel keys the same. It’s also not unique to Beethoven. Also, when a Beethoven piece in a major key has a PAC it’s to the major I and likewise for minor. So he might mix modes in the middle, but he still retains the sense of the home mode.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Well, they don't need two articles, since Beethoven considered them one and the same. ;-)

Comment: @Aaron - If that were really true, I'd expect the Waldstein sonata, which is in C major, to actually get mentioned in "Beethoven and C minor" articles. Haven't found a single mention in any such article so far (and I checked the Wikipedia one just now again).

Comment: @Dekkadeci Just to make sure it's clear, my comment was entirely tongue-in-cheek. As is this one, about the Waldstein sonata, which is commonly misidentified as C major, but which is actually in C minor — the two, of course, being one and the same. (And, just to be even more clear for everyone else, I think it's actually a very interesting question and hope someone can provide a well-documented answer.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci Funny we completed our formal analysis of the first movement of the Waldstein in class yesterday and the modal mixture came up. Particularly because the first (and only) cadence in the primary theme is a half cadence preceded by a C *minor* chord. My point being, modal mixture in the Waldstein is definitely well-known and discussed, whether or not it has made it into the articles you have checked. Perhaps the article writers feel that no more needs to be said about the Waldstein because it’s already famous for that half cadence and other C minor areas.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Huh, I remember reading a different (probably unconfirmed) source saying that the parallel major/minor keys were considered to be more equivalent and providing less drama/contrast than the relative major/minor keys in earlier Classical music. At the very least, Mozart *loves* using the parallel minor within his second theme groups of sonata-allegros and also often in transitions to prepare the exposition's second theme group's dominant key.

Comment: I suppose the video mentions using the functions in both modes with the same tonic interchangeably. For instance, a C major phrase ends with Fm-G7-Cm cadance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the key to understanding the idea is to separate the concepts of tonal and modal in regard to scale degrees and *functional* harmony versus modal *color*.

In a nutshell, the tonal scale degrees are `^1`, `^4`, and `^5`, and the modal scale degrees are `^3` and `^6`. `^1`, `^4`, and `^5` provide the roots for the all important tonic, subdominant, and dominant chords, while `^3` and `^6` provide the thirds for the tonic and subdominant chords. `^3` and `^6` can be either major or minor and so define the *mode* of a key.

To some extent you could say scale degrees `^2` and `^7` have mixed roles, but in regard to functional harmony the *raised* `^7` degree, the leading tone, is critical to dominant chords and it's "function" is to define the tonic in both major and minor keys.

Another way to say this is: the scale degrees `^1`, `^4`, `^5`, and leading tone `^7` do not vary between the major and minor forms of a key. The functional aspect of harmony doesn't change between major and minor forms of a key: `^5` goes to `^1`, leading tone `^7` goes to `^1`, and `^4` goes to `^3`. That's the essence of functional tonic/dominant harmony. The variable major or minor aspect of `^3` and `^6` only provides "color", determines the mode, for a key.

A common convention in harmonic analysis is to use upper case Roman numerals for major chord quality and lower case for minor quality, like `I` for a major triad and `i` for a minor triad. But there is also a convention *that does not distinguish major/minor quality* and only give upper case Roman numerals to indicate chord roots. By that second convention `IV V I` only means "subdominant, dominant, tonic triads with no regard to modal quality.

So, we can define harmonic function without knowing the details of mode. You can think of that as either modal ambivalence or as accepting a much more "colorful" harmonic style. I suppose if you push that idea far enough you could say there really aren't separate major and minor tonalities but simply a single tonality. There is no name for it, except perhaps "tonal harmony."

Comment: I like this answer. Shouldn't (4th para.) ^5 stay as ^5 though? +1.

Comment: Yes, for upper voices, I meant in the bass.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really basic answer, but it is one example I can think of where I have seen this. The source you provide doesn't seem to give a lot of detail about what he means as "identical", but I would say that strictly speaking only identical things are identical. One way you can treat the parallel major and minor keys *similar*, though, is its relationship to the dominant chord. This is something I have noticed in some of Bach's and Ponce's music.

One thing you could do to give a song a strong sense of thematicism, while getting a novel sound is repeat an idea you already did in the major key in the parallel minor later in the song. It is very easy to modulate to the parallel minor because it has the same dominant chord.

The simplest example I can think of that I have seen in Ponce's music is this: "my musical idea is that the bass line is going to walk up the scale. I will harmonize then with the tonic and dominant chords where possible, and then I will repeat this same idea later using a similar melody in the parallel minor. "

Can't find a perfect example in the same song, but here is one. In the Allemande of Ponce's suite in Am he uses the pattern I show below in A minor. Then in the next song, the Sarabande from that suite, he uses that pattern in A major. I tried to offset and stretch the scores so you can see the patterns line up.

**My Simplified Example**
[image: simplified example]

**Example from Ponce Suite in La Minuer**
[image: Ponce example]

Comment: "One way you can treat the parallel major and minor keys similar, though, is it's relationship to the dominant chord".  I think you are correct here. In tonic-dominant harmony, a C harmonic minor scale will work perfectly well on the G7. That is currently my line of thinking?